# JavaScript: Get Class value within internal function

Tags: javascript

I have got a class, I make a new instance of this class for two elements.

When clicked, these elements should then add a class to another element, however the `console.log` is displaying `undefined`, any ideas why?

```
// Wait for document to load
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    class menuControl {
      constructor(obj, child) {
        this.state = 0;
        this.child = child;
        this.elm = obj;
      }

      toggleActive() {
        if (this.state === 1) {
          this.state = 0; removeClass(this.child, 'toggled');
        } else {
          console.log(this.child);
          this.active = 1; addClass(this.child, 'toggled');
        }
      }

    }

    // Global Variables
    var usedcars = new menuControl(doc('usedcars__trigger'), doc('listitem__search'));
    var menu = new menuControl(doc('megamenu__trigger'), doc('megamenu'));
    function doc(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

    (usedcars.elm).addEventListener('click', usedcars.toggleActive);

  }, false);
```

Comment: To get the right `this`, pass `usedcars.toggleActive.bind(usedcars)` to `addEventListener()`

Comment: @Alnitak so my event listener would be `(usedcars.elm).addEventListener('click', usedcars.toggleActive.bind(this));`? As this isn't working.

Comment: ah - you're not binding _within_ the class, so you'd have to supply `usedcars` as the parameter to `bind()`.  Alternatively, do `addEventListener('click', () => usedcars.toggleActive())`

Comment: the correct form would be `usedcars.elm.addEventListener('click', usedcars.toggleActive.bind(usedcars))`

Comment: (It's unusual for a control of this nature to rely on external code to bind its event listeners which is what caught me out first time around)